# Android MkDirs is Failing

Tags: java, android, mkdir

It seems that whenever I use MkDirs or save the file by itself (without making a directory), it fails. The app does have permission to write and read storage, as this was checked in the main activity and the activity will not even start if permission is not granted. I am running this on Android 8.1.0 on a Pixel 2 XL. Using DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, and others like that have also not worked. It feels like a permissions or other storage issue, but I am not so sure.

```
 public void onInput(MaterialDialog dialog, CharSequence input) {
                            inputNormal = textContent.getText().toString();

                            File rootFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString(), "Sorbet");
                            if (!rootFolder.exists()) {
                                rootFolder.mkdirs();
                            }
                            try {
                                File file = new File(rootFolder, input.toString()+".txt");
                                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
                                writer.write(inputNormal);
                                writer.newLine();
                                writer.flush();
                                writer.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
```

For context, here is the code that I use to check permissions. This is fully working, as the dialog shows to grant permission, and the permission shows as granted in the system settings for the app.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Snackbar errorBar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.content_main), getString(R.string.snackbar_error),
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .setAction(getString(R.string.allow_access), new View.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                            STORAGE_PERMISSION_RC);
                                }
                            });
                    errorBar.show();
                }
                if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    startActivity(NoteCreateIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
    else{
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(NoteCreateIntent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please post the exact error you are getting.

Comment: @bremen_matt there is no error. Nothing in LogCat, no crash, nothing. The directory is just simply not being created. The strange thing is, it used to work back on my Pixel 1, but no longer works on my Pixel 2 XL, any of my emulators, or any other devices ive tested with

Comment: You should log the variable `rootFolder`. I would guess that it is not what you think it is

Comment: try this one File rootFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+ "/Sorbet");

Comment: `rootFolder.mkdirs();`. Check the return value and handle accordingly: `if(!rootFolder.mkdirs()){Toast ( ... could not create directory ....); return;}`.;

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()` That should be `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` only.

Comment: I have tried that as well, with the same result. It is possible that this could be an issue with permissions itself, since the file wont create even withut mkdirs

Comment: Permission? Did you ask for write external storage? WRITE?

Comment: @MJonesDev. Any update? If none of our suggestions helped, please write your own so that the next person that comes across this question will know how to solve this issue.

Comment: @greenapps I have both read and write permissions in my app, and the device has granted them.

Comment: @bremen_matt I am still working on this. I will make my own suggestion when i fix the issue, but so far, none of the suggestions given have worked.

Comment: @greenapps Thank you for the suggestion. I asked for WRITE in my manifest, but did not specify it in my Java classes. Due to this, it was not working. I was under the assumption that asking for READ automatically granted WRITE, as they are in the same permission group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed. This was a permission issue with Android. In order to write files, you have to explicitly ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, something that I dismissed.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        val permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(applicationContext,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

        //Granted Permission
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            val sorbetDirectory = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path + "/Sorbet")
            sorbetDirectory.mkdirs()
        }

        //Denied Permission
        if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
            MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
                    .title(com.marlonjones.sorbet.R.string.titleP)
                    .content(com.marlonjones.sorbet.R.string.perm_content)
                    .positiveText(com.marlonjones.sorbet.R.string.ok)
                    .onPositive { dialog, which ->
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this@MainActivity,
                                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),
                                STORAGE_PERMISSION_RC)
                    }
                    .show()
        }

    }
```

Comment: You should not have posted this as an answer. And certainly not as your answer. I already had told what had to be done.

Comment: Then post an answer, and he can mark it as correct. He cannot mark an invisible answer

Answer (score 1):

I would try, just temporarily, switching the folder that you are putting files in from

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

to

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)
```

This directory (along with the music, videos, etc. directories) always seems to be well-defined, whereas the `getExternalStorageDirectory` varies from device to device.

I would suspect that `getExternalStorageDirectory` is just not returning the correct value. You should try saving in a different directory to ensure that the error is not due to some other part of your code.

If you can't save to the `downloads` folder, then the error is likely in some other part of your code.

If you can save to the `downloads` folder, then the error is most likely due to something weird with the path returned by `getExternalStorageDirectory()`.

---

### EDIT

Two more suggestions:

1. Log the value of rootFolder. You need to triple check to make sure that it is what you think it should be. Please edit the question with this value.
2. `mkdirs` returns a boolean indicating whether the directory was made. That command CAN fail, typically if there is a permissions issue. You should also log the return value of that command. If, for instance, `mkdirs` returns false, then you know where the problem lies.

Comment: Unfortunately, this has not worked either. The file did not show up in DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS. Could it possibly be a permissions issue?

Comment: I would suggest two more things. First, log the value of `rootFolder`. You need to triple check to make sure that it is what you think it should be. It would be go to edit the question with this value. Second, `mkdirs` returns a boolean indicating whether the directory was made. That command CAN fail, typically if there is a permissions issue. You should also log the return value of that command

Comment: the issue was that I did not ask for WRITE_EXTERNAL. I was under the assumption that asking for Read External or the entire Permission Group automatically granted permission to this. However, it did not.