# Android: mkdir failing

Tags: java, android

I have come back to a project after a few months and the mkdir is failing. The app has permission to write to storage and I'm at a bit of a loss.

I've tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49881270/8328420) but that didn't get me anywhere and other answers I've found wer e about program structure. These are the first lines of a utility function that writes a collection of items to a csv so they weren't very applicable.

Debug info inline with code:

[image: Debug info inline with code]

```
String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
String fileName;
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "appFolder");

boolean res = true;
if(!directory.exists()){
    res = directory.mkdirs();
    Log.d("DirectoryResult", Boolean.toString(res));
}
```

The app is being run from android studio.

Is there anything other than permissions that would cause mkdir to fail either in general or in the "storage/emulated/0" directory?

Comment: You cannot create directories off of the root of external storage on Android 11+.

Comment: You need to use either some public/app directory or ask the user where to save it.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/niharika2810/ScopedStorageDemo. this is  implementation of scoped storage, recommended by google in android 10+.